# Make FullCalendar fetch events data from a nested JSON structure

Tags: fullcalendar

I am sending events not as a JSON array, but like this:

```
{"result":"success",
                "events":[
                    {"end":"2012-07-14T11:00:00", "description":"1", "title":"2", "start":"2012-07-14T07:00:00"},
                    {"end":"2012-07-14T11:00:00", "description":"3", "title":"4", "start":"2012-07-14T07:00:00"}
                ]}
```

And receive it from [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#options) this way:

```
        events:{
            url:'/sweatiquette/calendar/events/',
            type:'POST',
            allDayDefault:false,
            data:{action:'get'}
        }
```

I wonder if I can configure FullCalendar to process data from "events" field if I send it using this structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/ "Events as a function". 
Fetch your JSON object and parse the events-array from there.